# Invisible chart area during print and in exported PDF file in spreadsheet created by service account with Google Sheets API (Node.js) in shared folder

Tags: charts, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

I'm creating a spreadsheet in Node.js environment in shared folder using service account with Google Sheets API v.4 in few steps:

1. Create spreadsheet itself in shared folder with "Can Edit" permission for service account.
2. Inserting some data and performing some text formats using spreadsheet ID received as callback from previous step.
3. Inserting chart using as income data the data inserted in prevoius step.

As the result I have a spreadsheet with expected result (text data and horizontal bar chart on same sheet). But when I'm trying to send it on printer, or download as PDF-file - chart area becomes completely invisible. I didn't find any option in official documentation about possible chart visibility during printing or something like this. And when I'm replacing this created chart with manually created one - everything is ok, I can print it and export to PDF.

**So, what is the problem? Am I missing something? Or it's some bug?**

**index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const FOLDER_ID = '1xG3xHhrucB4AGLmnd8T2TmCyqhmPux5Q';

var timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
console.log(`timeStamp at startup = ${timeStamp}`);

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: 'credentials.json',
    scopes: SCOPES
});

process.env.HTTPS_PROXY = 'http://10.5.0.20:3128';

const sheets = google.sheets({
    version: 'v4',
    auth: auth,
    proxy: 'http://10.5.0.20:3128'
});

const drive = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: auth,
    proxy: 'http://10.5.0.20:3128'
});

function createFileName() {
    const now = new Date();
    let date = String(now.toISOString().slice(0, 10));
    let hours = String(now.getHours()).padStart(2, "0");
    let minutes = String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2, "0");
    let seconds = String(now.getSeconds()).padStart(2, "0");
    let humanDate = date.replaceAll('-', '.');
    humanDate = `${humanDate}_${hours}-${minutes}-${seconds}`;
    return humanDate;
}

async function saveFileLocally(filePath, data) {
    fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(data), error => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

app.get("/check", (req, res) => {
    res.send('server is online...');
});

app.post("/motivation", async (req, res) => {
    
    if(!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    
    try {
        const prizv = req.body.prizv;
        const name = req.body.name;
        const father = req.body.father;
        const sex = req.body.sex;
        const age = req.body.age;
        const factors = req.body.factors;
        const testName = 'motivation';
        const clientData = { prizv: prizv, name: name, father: father, sex: sex, age: age, factors: factors, testName: testName };

        const fileName = `${createFileName()}_${prizv}`;
        const filePath = `files/${testName}/${fileName}.txt`;

        const isSaved = await saveFileLocally(filePath, clientData);

        if (isSaved) {
            console.log(`file is saved locally....`);
            const sheetID = await createSheetToGoogleDIsk(clientData, fileName);
            res.send(sheetID);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
});

async function createSheetToGoogleDIsk(clientData, fileName) {
    
    const file = fileName;

    var sheetsMetadata = {
        name: file,
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
        parents: [FOLDER_ID]
    };

    const res2 = drive.files.create({
        resource: sheetsMetadata,
        fields: 'id'
    }, function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log('SheetID: ', file.data.id);
            const gSheetID = file.data.id;
            pasteDataToGoogleSheet(clientData, gSheetID);
            insertChartToGoogleSheet(gSheetID);
            return file.data.id;
        }
    });
}

async function insertChartToGoogleSheet(spreadsheetId) {
    
    spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId;
    let requests = [];
    // set font size for whole Sheet as 14
    requests.push({
        "repeatCell": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": 0,
                "startRowIndex": 0,
                "endRowIndex": 100,
            },
            "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                        "fontSize": 13,
                    },
                },
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.fontSize"
        },
    });
    // set header text format as Bold and 18 pt
    requests.push({
        "repeatCell": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": 0,
                "startRowIndex": 0,
                "endRowIndex": 2,
            },
            "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                        "fontSize": 18,
                        "bold": true
                    },
                },
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
        },
    });
    // set subheader text format as Bold and 15 pt
    requests.push({
        "repeatCell": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": 0,
                "startRowIndex": 3,
                "endRowIndex": 4,
            },
            "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                        "fontSize": 15,
                        "bold": true
                    },
                },
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
        },
    });
    // set client data as Bold
    requests.push({
        "repeatCell": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": 0,
                "startRowIndex": 5,
                "endRowIndex": 10,
                "startColumnIndex": 3,
                "endColumnIndex": 5
            },
            "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                        "fontSize": 13,
                        "bold": true
                    },
                },
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
        },
    });
    // set 1st column width as 20px
    requests.push({
        "updateDimensionProperties": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": 0,
                "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                "startIndex": 0,
                "endIndex": 1
            },
                "properties": {
                "pixelSize": 20
            },
            "fields": "pixelSize"
        }
    });
    // set 4st column width as 150px
    requests.push({
        "updateDimensionProperties": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": 0,
                "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                "startIndex": 3,
                "endIndex": 4
            },
                "properties": {
                "pixelSize": 150
            },
            "fields": "pixelSize"
        }
    });
    // set bold factors Values
    requests.push({
        "repeatCell": {
            "range": {
                "sheetId": 0,
                "startRowIndex": 33,
                "endRowIndex": 45,
                "startColumnIndex": 4,
                "endColumnIndex": 5
            },
            "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                    "textFormat": {
                        "fontSize": 13,
                        "bold": true
                    },
                },
            },
            "fields": "userEnteredFormat(textFormat)"
        },
    });
    requests.push({
        "addChart": {
            "chart": {
                "chartId": 1,
                "spec": {
                    "titleTextFormat": {
                    },
                    "basicChart": {
                        "chartType": "BAR",
                        "axis": [
                            {
                                "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                            },
                            {
                                "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                            }
                        ],
                        "domains": [
                            {
                                "domain": {
                                    "sourceRange": {
                                        "sources": [
                                            {
                                                "sheetId": 0,
                                                "startRowIndex": 33,
                                                "endRowIndex": 45,
                                                "startColumnIndex": 1,
                                                "endColumnIndex": 2
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                },
                            }
                        ],
                        "series": [
                            {
                                "series": {
                                    "sourceRange": {
                                        "sources": [
                                            {
                                                "sheetId": 0,
                                                "startRowIndex": 33,
                                                "endRowIndex": 45,
                                                "startColumnIndex": 4,
                                                "endColumnIndex": 5
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "targetAxis": "BOTTOM_AXIS"
                            }
                        ],
                    },
                },
                "position": {
                    "overlayPosition": {
                        "anchorCell": {
                            "sheetId": 0,
                            "rowIndex": 11,
                            "columnIndex": 1
                        },
                        "offsetXPixels": 0,
                        "offsetYPixels": -7,
                        "widthPixels": 800,
                        "heightPixels": 450
                    },
                },
                "border": {
                    "color": {
                        "red": 1,
                        "green": 1,
                        "blue": 1,
                        "alpha": 0
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    });
    const batchUpdateRequest = { requests };
    sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId,
        resource: batchUpdateRequest,
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            // Handle error
            console.log(err);
            return false
        } else {
            console.log(`${result.updatedCells} chart inserted`);
            return spreadsheetId
        }
    });
}

async function pasteDataToGoogleSheet(clientData, sheetId) {
    ecxelID = sheetId;
    let data1 = [
        ["Тест «Мотиваційний особистісний профіль»"], [""], ["Результати тестування"], [""], ["Прізвище"], ["Імя"], ["По-батькові"], ["Вік"], ["Стать"]
    ];
    let data2 = [
        [clientData.prizv], [clientData.name], [clientData.father], [clientData.age], [clientData.sex]
    ];
    let factorsLabels1_6 = [
        ["1. Матеріальна винагорода:"], ["2. Комфортні умови:"], ["3. Структурованість роботи:"], ["4. Соціальні контакти:"], ["5. Довірливі стосунки:"], ["6. Визнання:"]
    ];
    let factors1_6 = [
        [clientData.factors.factor1], [clientData.factors.factor2], [clientData.factors.factor3], [clientData.factors.factor4], [clientData.factors.factor5], [clientData.factors.factor6]
    ];
    let factorsLabels7_12 = [
        ["7. Досягнення мети:"], ["8. Влада і вплив:"], ["9. Відсутність рутини:"], ["10. Креативність:"], ["11. Самовдосконалення і розвиток:"], ["12. Цікава і корисна діяльність:"]
    ];
    let factors7_12 = [
        [clientData.factors.factor7], [clientData.factors.factor8], [clientData.factors.factor9], [clientData.factors.factor10], [clientData.factors.factor11], [clientData.factors.factor12]
    ];
    const data = [{
            range: "B2:B10",
            values: data1,
        },
        {
            range: "D6:D10",
            values: data2,
        },
        {
            range: "B34:B39",
            values: factorsLabels1_6,
        },
        {
            range: "E34:E39",
            values: factors1_6,
        },
        {
            range: "B40:B45",
            values: factorsLabels7_12,
        },
        {
            range: "E40:E45",
            values: factors7_12,
        }
    ];
    const resource = {
        data,
        valueInputOption: 'RAW',
    };
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
        spreadsheetId: ecxelID,
        resource: resource,
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            // Handle error
            console.log(err);
            return false
        } else {
            console.log(`${result.updatedCells} cells data inserted`);
            return spreadsheetId;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike, sure. I've edit my post

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, where is the script of `download as PDF-file`?

Comment: @Tanaike, I'm trying to download PDF manually from Google Disk in browser "File -> Download -> PDF"

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `when I'm trying to send it on printer, or download as PDF-file - chart area becomes completele invisible.`, in this case, you manually download the Spreadsheet with your browser as PDF file, and when you see the Spreadsheet on your browser, you can see the chart. But when you see the downloaded PDF file, no chart is existing. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Yes, as you described. Here is the link [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oj7p8XHO-8ya5-kwsC1zMO--DJt44-CmOFD_SHXIpSg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I could confirm your issue. By this, I posted a modification point in my answer. Could you please confirm it? When I tested the above modification, I could confirm that your issue could be removed. But, if that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, it's works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could confirm your situation. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
"offsetXPixels": 0,
"offsetYPixels": -7,
"widthPixels": 800,
"heightPixels": 450
```

#### To:

```
"offsetXPixels": 0,
"offsetYPixels": 0, // Modified
"widthPixels": 800,
"heightPixels": 450
```

or

```
"widthPixels": 800,
"heightPixels": 450
```

- When the values of `offsetXPixels` and `offsetYPixels` are the negative values, it was found that such an issue occurs.
- When the values of `offsetXPixels` and `offsetYPixels` are `0`, these values are not required to be included because of the default value.

#### Note:

- When I tested the above modification, I could confirm that your issue could be removed.

#### Reference:

- [EmbeddedObjectPosition](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#EmbeddedObjectPosition)

Comment: Yes! Problem is fixed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @regman Thank you for your response.